# CSS shorthand possible?

Tags: css

Do you know if there's a way to combine this CSS?

```
.a:hover .RemoveImg, .b:hover .RemoveImg, .c:hover .RemoveImg {
    display: inline;
}
```

I'm thinking it should be the below, but it doesn't work.

```
.a:hover, .b:hover, .c:hover .RemoveImg 
    display: inline;
}
```

My desired outcome is whenever a, b, or c is hovered, the RemoveImg class that is within each of those separate classes will be displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: You would be looking at a CSS-preprocessor. Otherwise no, there is no short-hand for selectors in CSS.

Comment: @Terry is right or use javascript

Comment: Have you heard of [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/)?

Comment: Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or some other CSS pre-processor

Comment: @Almis JS would be a bit heavy-handed though ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are no shorthands available or CSS selectors: only property and property values. However, you can look into using a CSS pre-processing language like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) to do the work for you, but which requires compiling to generate a CSS file later.

The the SCSS/[SASS](http://sass-lang.com) syntax, it would be something like this:

```
.a, .b, .c {
    &:hover .RemoveImg {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

... which will [compile into the selector combination](http://sassmeister.com/gist/4285bb4d1746c411f789) you desire:

```
.a:hover .RemoveImg, .b:hover .RemoveImg, .c:hover .RemoveImg {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't use SASS so I'll just keep the long form for now.